# opinion on using native Visual C++ projects vs makefile project

Tags: c++, cross-platform, project-management

I'm working on a cross-platform C/C++ code base that has Visual C++ (super majority) & XCode developers. It also needs to compile on Linux, because that's where it's deployed. We are currently using a complicated Unix makefile that's called from Visual C++, XCode, & Unix command line.

However, the makefile project causes several productivity losses for Visual C++ developers:

1. Slower build times
2. Intellisense & text search don't work well for files not directly referenced in project
3. No .h dependency generation (not clear how to do on Windows)

Adding a native Visual C++ project has the following downsides:

1. lots of work to manage all those separate platform configuration as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51859/using-makefile-instead-of-solution-project-files-under-visual-studio-2005) Maybe VC++ 2010's hierarchical property sheets will help.
2. more work due to syncing makefile with native project

Currently, I'm considering to add a native project for Windows developers. Can anyone offer their experience on what's best or suggest how those problems with either approach can be reduced.

I have considered CMake and personally would use it, but it's going to be hard to convince other people to learn cmake & syncing it with the native projects would be an issue.

Comment: CMake is only an issue if you LIKE wasting time.  Those who enjoy having to keep complex makefile systems in order are going to absolutely hate it because it'll require that they put down their busywork and do something significant.

Answer (score 3):

> I have considered CMake and personally would use it, but it's going to be hard to convince other people to learn cmake & syncing it with the native projects would be an issue.

The nice thing about CMake is that it builds ALL of the configurations for you.  You would setup a single CMake project, and then use it to generate VS solutions, XCode projects, and unix makefiles for you.

It's a huge improvement - everybody gets to work in their "native" environment, whether they're on Windows, Mac, or Unix.

Comment: does it allow you to go backwards though?   ie,  if you add stuff via visual studio,  can you get CMake to synch the changes back into the global project?

Comment: No it doesn't allow syncing back. Think of it like your current makefile implementation. You change your CMakeLists.txt once, commit. Everyone rebuild. Done.

Comment: @Keith: Yes - you have to learn to edit the CMakeLists.txt file.  Once you've got that down, it's super easy... It also does some nice things in relation to out of source builds, which is very nice when working cross platform for keeping your source control clean...

Answer (score 0):

I've handled this by writing my own converter that would synch scripts for various embedded development environments.    If something like the above answer of using CMake does all that for you, then that would be the way to go. But if its too complex, rolling your own custom tool is not that hard.  Just has to synch both ways.

Also, if you don't have it.    Visual Assist for visual studio is awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not a fan of makefile generators, *cmake*, *qmake* and the like.

I am a fan of make. We have a single makefile (well, several actually but they include each other and there is no recursive make involved) which knows all of the project dependencies on all platforms (windows, wince, linux, mac, ...). This gives:

- Makefile is really no more than a list of sources (include dependencies are auto-generated during the build)
- Same build command on each platform, apart from specifying the tool chain
- Build uses all my CPUs
- Very short time-to-do-nothing
- Developers can use whatever IDE they fancy

  - vim, emacs, qtcreator, eclipse, XCode all in use
  - I often use VC++ when on Windows (for the debugger)
- Scriptable. Great way to automate your tests

Nice.